# Flume folder routing based on HTTP header

Tags: hadoop, curl, cloudera, flume

Using curl and Flume, I would like to post CSV files on my local machine/HDFS at different locations based on the values of the HTTP header. For example, for this HTTP header (Network-Element: GGSN) I would like my files to be stored on my local machine in a folder named GGSN.

I have the following Flume configuration

- a HTTP source
- a memory channel
- a HDFS sink that routes the events files to different locations depending on the HTTP header

I then post CSV files using curl:

```
find /path/files -type f -exec curl -X POST http://localhost:9043 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Network-Element: GGSN" --data-binary "@{}" -v \;
```

These logs are generated:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9043 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9043 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:9043
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml
> Network-Element: GGSN
> Content-Length: 972660
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Flume logs show the following:

```
2015-03-16 19:41:14,887 DEBUG org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobHandler: requestHeaders: {Expect=100-continue, Host=localhost:9043, Content-Length=972660, Network-Element=GGSN, User-Agent=curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2, Content-Type=text/xml, Accept=*/*}
2015-03-16 19:41:14,891 DEBUG org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobHandler: blobEvent: [Event headers = {Content-Type=text/xml}, body.length = 972660 ]
```

I use this Flume configuration:

```
sa.sources  = httpsource1
sa.channels = memorychannel1
sa.sinks    = localsink1

sa.sources.httpsource1.type     = http
sa.sources.httpsource1.handler     = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobHandler
sa.sources.httpsource1.port     = 9043
sa.sources.httpsource1.channels = memorychannel1

sa.channels.memorychannel1.type   = memory
sa.channels.memorychannel1.capacity   = 10000
sa.channels.memorychannel1.transactionCapacity   = 1000

sa.sinks.localsink1.type         = file_roll
sa.sinks.localsink1.channel      = memorychannel1
sa.sinks.localsink1.sink.directory   = /path/%{Network-Element}
sa.sinks.localsink1.sink.rollInterval = 36000
```

For some reason files cannot be placed under this path: /path/%{Network-Element}
It looks like this path does not exist, even if I have manually created the GGSN folder and set all the permissions to it.

Comment: You have configured a channel named `eniq-memorychannel1-uat` but then you configure a `memorychannel1` channel; they must match AFAIK. The same for the sink (`eniq-localsink1-uat` vs `localsink1`).

Comment: I corrected. It was a typo. I tried to simplify the code I put into the example. The issue is not this of course. Do you have any other ideas?